# Make Window Close, but application stay alive using user control

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

That question may need to be revised. I'm making a C# WPF program that will be deployed on multiple Tablets. Each of those tablets have different resolutions and orientations. This is why I'm using WPF. So I decided to make a Window foreach tablet. Since this window is to configure the program I decided to make "Buttons" (user controls) that have the mouse down property filled in with what I want that particular button to do. I started with the Close buttons since I figured it would be the easiest. I go the close button looking good on the Window and in that particular Tablet. The Window's ShowDialog method is called by the main application (winforms... it is slowly transitioning to use WPF entirely) I tried setting the DialogResult but I was getting a NullReference Error. I tried Application.Current.ShutDown() (which Current is null) So I'm not sure how to do this. The end game I want to be able to just add a button (say to setup the com port) to the window and that button works with no addtional code.

Comment: So, to clarify: You have a WinForms app that launches a WPF dialog. You are creating custom chrome for the dialog, and want to know how to close it with a button?

Comment: that is the first step yeah. Next will be to do similar things with a ComPort Button (to set the com port and baud rate) another button to set the brightness. I plan on (and not sure if it is possible) to have each button set the Content of a ContentControl. I think i found a fix for the close button. I found a small blippet on Style. So I set the style and Set the IsDefault=True. I'll test it right now.

Comment: Well, it is certainly possible to map arbitrary blocks of code to a button click in WPF. I'd look at MVVM and `ICommand`. You create a `ViewModel` that exposes `ICommand`s that implement this sort of functionality. Then your buttons bind their `Command` property to the exposed `ICommand` properties of the `ViewModel`. I think the close button will be a different case in that it acts solely on the view, so you wouldn't expose a close command on your `ViewModel`.

Comment: An application will not stay if the last window is closed. You need to keep a window hidden but open somewhere to keep the application running.